# How to do reverse geocoding with Cordova Geolocation API to get City and Country?

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation, hybrid-mobile-app, reverse-geocoding

I am building a hybrid mobile application using Intel's App Framework for user interface and Cordova to access the native device functionalities.

As a part of the development, I need to get the user's location(City and Country) and show it in a text box.

By using the code below, I am able to get the Latitude and Longitude and show it in two different text boxes(with ID latitude and longitude respectively). How can I translate the latitude and longitude to City and Country.

```
  function Geolocation() {
                    var onSuccess = function(position) {
                        document.getElementById('latitude').value = position.coords.latitude;
                        document.getElementById('longitude').value = position.coords.longitude;                    
                    };
                    var onFail = function() {
                        navigator.notification.alert('Cannot get the location');
                    };
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onFail, {maximumAge:0, timeout:5000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
                }
```

Note - I don't use any other plugin other than Cordova's Geolocation to handle location services in my app. This is a hybrid app but currently I am working on the Android version of the app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called *reverse geocoding* are there are many services out there to do that - eg. Google Maps, OpenStreetMaps and many more.

I love OpenStreetMaps because it's **very** easy to do. Just a JSONP callback:

> http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=-23.5880894&lon=-46.6321951&format=json&json_callback=my_callback

So you can just make an Ajax request to this URL and get the desired values. For example:

```
function showCountry(lat, lon) {
    $.getJSON('//nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?json_callback=?&format=json', {lat: lat, lon: lon}, function(data) {
       alert(data.address.country);
   });
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. Should I use this along with Cordova ?

Comment: I am unable to use this in my Windows phone app.`function showCountry(lat, lon) {

    $.post('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse/', { format:'json',lat: lat, lon: lon }, function (data) {
        alert(data.address.country);
    });
}` Am able to view the JSON in the browser though.